# Postgres strategy for UPDATE SET x = NULL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, vacuum

It is not clear the strategy Postgres takes when columns are set to `NULL`:

```
UPDATE tbl SET
  col1 = NULL,
  col2 = NULL
WHERE created < current_date - INTERVAL '1 year';
```

Documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html is a bit lengthy and techy so I cannot reliably deduce:

**if setting to NULL is performed in place or affected rows/pages are copied**?

Looks like any UPDATE should create new row for MVCC semantic but what if setting to NULL is a special case?

For GDPR conformance I think to null every personal historical data and I try to understand implications of massive periodic `UPDATE SET x = NULL`. Should I think of `VACUUM` after that?

Comment: Why do you think setting anything to null should be a special case?

Comment: Because I'm not an expert of Postgre. I know some principles but any wizard would surprise me for sure with some obscure Postgre semantic ))

Comment: If you are really concerned, you will have to do that in all of your backups as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PostgreSQL never performs an `UPDATE` by modifying the existing data in place.  If you set columns to `NULL`, a new row version will be created just as with any other `UPDATE`, and the previous row versions will remain until `VACUUM` reclaims them.

But be warned that

- `VACUUM` will only delete the old row version if there is no long running transaction that still might need old data.
- `VACUUM` will not overwrite the data, so the old value will still be on disk until the space is reused.

Concerning the GDPR, [the wording is](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32016R0679#d1e2589-1-1):

> The data subject shall have the right to obtain from the controller the erasure of personal data concerning him or her without undue delay and the controller shall have the obligation to erase personal data without undue delay

The term “erasure” is nowhere defined in that law, so it is subject to interpretation. My bet is that few enough people understand the inner workings of PostgreSQL well enough to contest that `DELETE` is erasure. And it would take a data forensics expert with advanced PostgreSQL knowledge to retrieve such data. Once `VACUUM` has run, it is nigh impossible to do that. If I were called to court as an expert witness, I would say that anybody who has run `DELETE` in the database has taken all possible steps to erase the data.

If you feel paranoid, schedule a regular `VACUUM` on the table in question, and make sure that you have no long running transactions. Any worry beyond that is silly.

Comment: Wow! As always a great in-depth answer with extra info that originally wasn't considered (about forensics analysis). As the subject DB is cloud managed I think `DELETE` + `VACUUM` + ensuring all relevant transactions are closed are enough. Thanks I am not a layer and not in a charge of resolving a problem of GDPR +  Cloud provider.